How to keep mat table paginator at selected page after refresh?
I am using mat table to show data and my API gives page-wise data.
Now, first time it renders and then user changes the page and refreshes the page after, then I want to show the second page and not the first one.
To do that I have saved the pageIndex to local storage and retrieve it when the page refreshes and my API also calls the second page, but the pagination options are wrong as:
Mat Page Options After refesh
Which is showing 1-8; instead it should show 9-15 and also navigation is wrong as it is last page.
Here is my HTML
<mat-paginator
      class="mat-paginator-sticky"
      [hidden]="pageLength <= pageSizeOptions[0]"
      [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
      [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
      [length]="pageLength"
      [pageIndex]="page.pageIndex"
      (page)="pageChange($event)"
      aria-label="Select page of users"
    ></mat-paginator>

Here is ts file code snippets
constructor() {
     // Retrieve and set the current page index
     const savedPageIndex = localStorage.getItem('currentPageIndex');
     if (savedPageIndex) {
       this.page.pageIndex = +savedPageIndex;
       
     }
  }

I tried changes as
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.dataSource) {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          this.paginator.pageIndex = this.page.pageIndex;
          this.paginator.pageSize = this.page.pageSize;
          this.paginator.length = this.pageLength;
          this.paginator._changePageSize(this.paginator.pageSize);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
         
      }
    });
  }

I am expecting a way to change or correct the page range label and next prev buttons.

do you have a defined number of pages?

Yes initialized value:
pageLength: number = 0;
page: PageEvent = {
previousPageIndex: 0,
pageIndex: 0,
pageSize: 8,
length: 0,
};

I think what we have here is a case of the paginator not correctly synchronized with the current page index and page size.
You will need to modify your code a bit:
for example:
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';  // Adjust this import to your actual API service

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
  pageSizeOptions = [8, 16, 24];  // Your page size options
  page = {
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 8
  };
  totalItems = 15;  // Total number of items in your data set

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {  // Inject your API service
    // Retrieve and set the current page index and page size
    const savedPageIndex = localStorage.getItem('currentPageIndex');
    const savedPageSize = localStorage.getItem('currentPageSize');
    if (savedPageIndex) {
      this.page.pageIndex = +savedPageIndex;
    }
    if (savedPageSize) {
      this.page.pageSize = +savedPageSize;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Fetch initial data
    this.fetchData(this.page.pageIndex, this.page.pageSize);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let isPaginatorInitialized = false;
    while (!isPaginatorInitialized) {
      if (this.paginator) {
        this.paginator.pageIndex = this.page.pageIndex;
        this.paginator.pageSize = this.page.pageSize;
        this.paginator.length = this.totalItems;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        isPaginatorInitialized = true;
      }
    }

    this.paginator.page.subscribe(event => {
      this.pageChange(event);
    });
  }

  fetchData(pageIndex: number, pageSize: number): void {
    // Call your API here to fetch data based on pageIndex and pageSize
    this.apiService.getData(pageIndex, pageSize).subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data.items;
      
      // Update paginator length and pageIndex
      this.paginator.length = this.totalItems;
      this.paginator.pageIndex = pageIndex;
      this.paginator.pageSize = pageSize;
    });
  }

  pageChange(event: any): void {
    this.page.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
    this.page.pageSize = event.pageSize;

    // Save the current page index and size to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('currentPageIndex', this.page.pageIndex.toString());
    localStorage.setItem('currentPageSize', this.page.pageSize.toString());

    // Fetch new data based on the current page index and size
    this.fetchData(this.page.pageIndex, this.page.pageSize);
  }
}

